# O que é opinionated software?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

O termo é usado em algumas discussões de programação. Eu nem sei a tradução dele.

Qual é a importância para programadores?

Comment: _Opinionated_ eu consumo traduzir como ter uma opinião forte sobre alguma coisa. _"My grandfather is an opinionated man"._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geralmente está se falando de alguma característica que o software impõe ao usuário, e se for para um programador, que ele não deixa você programar de forma diferente.

Como exemplo, é a filosofia oficial de Python que diz que só tem uma maneira de fazer as coisas. Este não é um bom exemplo porque na prática tem várias formas de fazer, mas teoricamente eles dizem que querem que só tenha uma.

O termo é bastante usando em ORMs e outros *frameworks*, onde alguns dizem que sabem o que é melhor para você e só deixam fazer daquele jeito, você não tem flexibilidade de mudar, pelo menos em certas partes.

Então ele pode dizer que você tem que usar *code first* em vez de *database first* para gerar os modelos (geralmente tem alguma ferramenta que faz importação do banco de dados para gerar código se form necessário).

Outro exemplo seria um software de wiki que impõe a forma de trabalhar sem dar muita margem de como mexer nisso.

A Apple é um exemplo de empresa que costuma fazer softwares bastante opinativos por isso as pessoas costumam dizer que você não compra o software deles, porque mesmo depois de pagar, eles ainda dizem o que você pode ou não fazer.

Não sei se a falta de opção é ser opinativo. Por exemplo, a maioria dos bancos de dados possuem apenas um *engine* de *storage*, mas o MySQL permite você escolher e até personalizar algum. Isso é ser não opinativo?

[image: insetos, um pelado como feature e outro todo arrumadinho como bug]

Eu acho que algo não é 100% opinativo ou não, tem certas características que são. Pode até ter um caso com todas as características, mas em programação deve ser algo bem ruim de usar.

Algumas pessoas podem dizer que Java é opinativo quando não deixa criar um operador personalizado. O que faria virtualmente todo software ser opinativo em algum ponto. Fica difícil traçar uma linha do que é opinião sobre como fazer algo ou falta de alguma característica.

Eu não sei dizer como costuma ser interpretado quando há "convenção sobre configuração", que é tem um *default* considerado opinativo, mas você pode mudar. Nunca vi uma definição canônica que diz claramente o que o termo é. É daqueles casos do termo nascer informalmente e cada um pode interpretar como achar melhor.

Já vi algumas pessoas dizendo sobre o software ser aberto (não só o código) para a comunidade participar ou recriar, o que faria dele não opinativo, mas eu tenho dúvidas se isso se encaixa bem.

Alguns dizem que ele faz você não poder sair dele (*lock-in*). Também não acho uma boa definição, esta seria outra questão, até porque quase qualquer software te obriga ficar nele se não fizer grande esforço para sair.

O que parece ser mais certo, que ele estabelece "boas práticas" e obriga você usar daquela forma.

Dar muita flexibilidade torna o software mais difícil de desenvolver e mater e torna ele mais difícil de usar (exceto se usar *convention over configuration*).

Algumas pessoas falam que ele escolhe qual é o "caminho dourado", mas pode deixar você seguir outros caminhos. Se a escolha for ruim você passa longe do produto.

Então ele facilita fazer o que o criador achou que é melhor para você, mas dificulta ou impossibilita fazer algo diferente disto. Provavelmente é um termo de usabilidade.

Quando a pessoa não domina muito o assunto parece que ele é bom. Um software é mais opinativo quanto mais for feito para leigos, pelo menos deveria ser assim.

Costuma-se alegar que eles são mais produtivos que os mais flexíveis.

Me parece que esses softwares tendem durar menos. Fazendo uma análise histórica, se eles não mudam de filosofia, a adoção tende a declinar em favor de um concorrente, mesmo indiretamente, mais moderno, com melhores "opiniões". E nem sempre é fácil mudar a filosofia de algo opinativo. Em alguns casos pode ser mais fácil, justamente por ser mais simples. Mas irá contra sua própria opinião.

Softwares mais opinativos tendem ser mais nichados. Eles sobrevivem bem onde as pessoas possuem poucas exigências.

Para tudo pode ter exceção, exceto os softwares opinativos.

Parece que o balanço até onde deve ser opinativo é importante. Todo mundo quer o fácil, até que ele não atenda sua demanda e aí quer a flexibilidade.

O que eu mais notei é que as pessoas não conseguem concordar muito quais softwares são opinativos ou não. E eu mesmo não classificaria algum exemplo da pessoa usando o critério dela. Por isso é um bom termo para ajudar definir algo, mas ele não consegue universalizar tudo, é altamente opinativo na hora de usar o termo. Ah... a ironia.

Gostei deste diagrama:

[image: Traça estados possíveis de acordo com a habilidade e o desafio serem baixos ou altos]

O termo em Português provavelmente é o que eu usei por todo o texto, o literal, até porque sem uma explicação ele não quer dizer muito, é um termo técnico, não deveria ser completamente intuitivo, apenas dar uma ideia do que seja.

Tentei fazer a resposta não ser opinativa :P

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 Não sei ao certo, mas a primeira vez que eu ouvi falar no termo foi quando estudei sobre o framework Ruby on Rails. Não sei se foi o framework que criou o termo ou se já existia, mas sempre faço a ligação desse termo com tal ferramenta do Ruby.

Comment: Sei que ele é um dos mais citados quando usa o termo. Eu tenho dúvidas se ele é tão opinativo assim, talvez usaram isso como marketing um pouco. Há quem use de forma positiva e há quem use como negativo. De fato deve ser um pouco, por isso as pessoas estão abandonando ele, conforme o que eu respondi :)